# Terminal Server/Citrix XenApp alternative?

Tags: windows, terminal-server, citrix

Is there something less costly than Citrix XenApp and something better than Windows TS?

The industry seems to be dominated by citrix.

I'm currently using Windows 2000 Server Terminal Server, but now I have to switch to something better because of performance/color issues.

I'm faced with 2 options:
1) Upgrade to Windows 2008 Server + TS (now has App publishing i think?)
2) Get Citrix XenApp

Any suggestions or anything I'm not aware of?

Comment: What performance and color issues are you having?

Answer (score 3):

TSPlus

Terminal Services Plus

tsplus.net  -  Been using them and it's been great.

Answer (score 2):

Graphon have a product named Go-Global. They use their own technology, and you don't have to pay TSE cals. You can even use an XP machine to log many users at the same time.

http://www.graphon.com/content/view/9/9/

They use less bandwidth than TSE, but a bit more than Citrix. They provide client for MacOSX and Linux too
If you are interested, i have a contact there

Comment: Hi Mathieu, does GraphOn have trials of their software?

Comment: what is the pricing of graphon?

Comment: sure, they have trial. Price is a bit higher than TSE cal i guess, but as with all editors, price is lower when quantity raise up

Comment: i found public price (no tse cal to buy):
http://www.planet-europe.fr/swreg.html

to get trial, feed this form (link to download received by mail):
http://www.planet-europe.fr/telechargement.html

Comment: I left my contact details on their website 5 days ago, still no response from them.

Comment: I just had a Webex demo with them last week. It looks pretty good, essentially works in a similar way to Citrix/TS except uses their own protocol and not RDP, so no TS or Citrix licencing. You can use a web browser client, on Windows, Mac or Linux, or Sun and others. They have a Windows Mobile client and an iPhone client imminent.

Answer (score 1):

Check Winflector (www.winflector.com). It is an alternative to Citrix XenApp, does not use Terminal Services/RDP. There's a free version for 2 users licensed for commercial use aswell.

Answer (score 0):

www.sun.com/sunray/

Answer (score 0):

Check out ThinWorx, www.thinworx.com.  They are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

http://slashdot.org/story/06/04/16/001224/Alternatives-to-Citrix-Remote-Computing has a long list

a few more not listed:

- www.desktopsites.com
- http://www.quest.com/vworkspace
- www.ericom.com
- http://www.nsuite.com/ privacy shell
- http://www.2x.com has free license for up to 3 users or so.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Thinstuff XP/VS Terminal Server for Windows](http://www.thinstuff.com/products/xpvs-server/) which "turns any Windows system into a full-blown Terminal Server".  I haven't tested them yet but their feature list and pricing looks compelling.